# What's the smallest and lightest way to supply 5V to a 1"x1" circuit board?

Tags: power-supply, 5v

I'm creating a payload that will need to be supported by a small structure. This payload contains a 555 timer which needs 5V. So far I've only found coin cell batteries and have been using a [LilyPad Coin Cell Battery Holder](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10730) that holds a 3V coin cell battery. On the underside of this, I've attached a [5V step-up breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10968) to supply a constant voltage to the chip.

This method is fairly heavy, though, and I'm looking for an easier, lighter way to supply 5V to the circuit. Does anyone have recommendations or ideas?

Comment: Not all 555 timers need 5V - it may be easier to redesign.

Comment: It might be simpler to stick two CR2016 cells in the same holder and step *down* to 5V. But I'd probably look for a chip that will run off 3V.

Comment: Look at Zinc-Air cells which have high mass and volume energy densities due to use of air as one reactant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you use a CMOS 555 that will operate happily from a 3V battery, even at the end of (battery) life?

If you actually need 5V for blinky LEDs or whatever, you will need a circuit very similar to the ones you are showing.. so you *could* save mass by designing a very thin and small custom PCB. You can easily get 2-layer PCBs as thin as 0.4mm and you could probably cram that stuff into 1/3 or 1/4 the area, and use more compact components for the diode and the capacitor, so the total mass should go down by a large factor.

For the ultimate in reduction, pick a very high frequency switching chip that has synchronous rectification, as as the [FAN4860](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FA/FAN4860.pdf), which operates at 3MHz with a tiny 1uH inductor and tiny 0402 ceramic capacitors. The chip itself is 1.2mm x 0.88mm x 0.5mm, almost an inhalation risk.

[image]

Here is a comparison of the chip size vs. the (relatively) massive SOT23-5 package used by the vendor you linked to:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, these are great ideas. I may go that direction or I'm considering using a TLC555CDR with an SO08 package and 0402/0603 components. That'll reduce my voltage demand to ~2V. Am I right in assuming that a coin cell battery is still my smallest power supply (without the 5V step up board) even with that reduction?

Comment: I think so- there are different sizes of button cells- the type used for hearing aids are very small (but check the voltage- you might need more than one).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an XY problem, better solved by designing to operate down to maybe 2.7v. However, to avoid a step up, you can use two miniature lithium batteries, and if necessary a linear dropper. http://www.powerstream.com/thin-lithium-ion.htm